# Speeding up jQuery Autocomplete initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, performance

I'm using multiple (100+) autocomplete fields on the same page, all with the same data source, and have noticed that the initialization of the autocomplete fields is a bit slow. From some profiling I've done it looks like the bottleneck is the creation of the menu (`this.menu = $( "<ul></ul>" )` and so forth in the source code).

It seems kind of unnecessary to create separate menues for each autocomplete field, and so I was wondering if someone knows of a way to make this initialization faster.

I was thinking of making jQuery UI just use the same menu (or preferably the same autocomplete object) on all the input fields, but I don't know how this could be done without modifying the plugin source code.

Comment: Can you provide some jQuery and HTML code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try only initializing the autocomplete field when the user clicks the field

Comment: +1 [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) technique, often a very good option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by initialise auto-complete on focus:

```
$(".complete").focus(function(){

    $(this).autocomplete({
        //your options  
    });

});
```

The field with auto-complete function needs the class "complete" off course.